# Assigning numbers in Netlogo to agents randomly

Tags: netlogo

I am implementing a model in Netlogo in which i want to divide agents into income groups. My question is: assuming  5% of agents, representing households earn incomes between $500-$600. Is there a code i can write that would allocate this income range randomly to the agents?-so that some of them will have 500, 550, 590 and so on up to 600

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you want exact numbers 500 to 600 by 10s, then you want something like `set income 500 + 10 * random 11`. If you want any number in the range 500 to 600 then something like `set income 500 + random-float 100`. Have a look at the various random functions (listed in the mathematical section of the user manual) for other ideas.

To have this only happen to 5% of agents:

```
ifelse random-float 1 <= 0.05
  [ set income .... (whichever from above) ]
  [ ... whatever you want to happen for the other 95% ]
```